# Update AngularFirestoreDocument not working

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm using Angular and Firestore

**What I want to do**

- Iterate over a `Firestore` collection
- Change the value of a field in each `AngularFirestoreDocument` within that collection

This is where I grab my `minutes` collection

```
export class MinutesComponent {
  minutesArray: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
  minutes: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.minutesArray = afs.collection<any>('minutes', ref => ref.orderBy('year', 'desc'));
    this.minutes = this.minutesArray.valueChanges();
    ...
  }
}
```

In my constructor, this is how I try to update each document

```
this.minutes.subscribe(minutes => {
  minutes.forEach(minute => {

  ####RETRIEVES INDIVIDUAL DOCUMENT FROM DATABASE 
  const minuteRef = this.afs.doc(`minutes/${minute.id}`);

  if (minute.month === 'January') {
    minuteRef.update({'month': 1 });
  } else if (minute.month === 'jan') {
    minuteRef.update({'month': 1 });
  } else {
    minuteRef.update({'month': 2 });
  }
});
```

Thoughts? I want to loop through the document collection and update a field value of each document in the collection.

For example, if

`document.month = january`

I would like to change this to

`document.month = 1`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`valueChanges()` doesn't include the id of your minutes item. If you need access to the id, you should use `snapshotChanges()`

change this line `this.minutes = this.minutesArray.valueChanges();`

to

```
this.minutes = this.minutesArray
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
        map(actions => actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data();
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
        }))
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim. This is much closer. Right now it's throwing this error: `ReferenceError: map is not defined`. Am I missing something from my imports up top? These are my imports so far. `Component, OnInit, AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument, AngularFirestoreCollection, Observable from RXJS observable`

Comment: Indeed! I am missing `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'`